# F# Intersecting two lists

Tags: f#

So I want to intersect two sorted lists, such that `intersect ([1;1;1;2;2], [1;1;2;4])` would return `[1;1;2]`. I've come this far:

```
let rec intersect (xs, xs') =
    match xs, xs' with
    | ([], [])             -> []
    | (x::tail, [])        -> []
    | ([], x'::tail')      -> []
    | (x::tail, x'::tail') -> if x = x' then x::intersect(tail, tail')
                              else intersect(tail, xs')
```

But I'm not quite sure where to go from here. The function takes a tuple containing two lists, and I assume that when the head of each list is equal to each other, I start building up a new list, but I'm missing something that I can't quite figure out and hope to get a hint on.

EDIT: I'm aware I can use library functions to easily solve this, but that's no fun :)

Comment: Are the input lists sorted?

Comment: Yes, they are. I'll add that information.

Comment: I have a solution but I won't post it... There are more cases to handle in the pattern match: what if only one of the lists is empty? There's another case to handle in the `if` expression: what if `x < x'`. Use `else` for that. Finally, don't reuse the name `xs` in the pattern match because you need the original `xs` for some of the cases. Same for `xs'`

Comment: `if` is an expression, not a statement. The last branch should just say `else`, not `else if`. You were closer with edit number 3.

Comment: I think I've got it now :). How does that deviate from your solution?

Comment: You're almost there but your function doesn't work if you swap the arguments around. I'll post mine as an answer.

Comment: I know you do not want to use library functions, but in my experience the faster way to do this is 1) Convert the lists to sets, 2) Take the set intersection, 3) Convert the set to a list, 4 ) Sort the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what I came up with:

```
let rec intersect xs ys =
    match xs, ys with
    | x::xs', y::ys' ->
        if   x = y then x :: intersect xs' ys'
        elif x < y then intersect xs' ys
        else            intersect xs  ys'
    | _ -> []
```

I removed the tupling of the arguments as I saw no reason for it.

`x::xs'` will only match with a non-empty list, so the base case match can be moved to the end and simplified to `_`.

I also changed the names. I find it's better to use the tick suffix only in names referring to the next iteration of an already existing value. In this case you have a list `xs` and its tail is `xs'`.

Comment: If you reorder your match cases you can simplify the last case to:
_ -> []

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you rename your arguments to `l1` and `l2` and match against `(x :: xs)` and `(y :: ys)` i.e.

```
let rec intersect (l1, l2) =
    match l1,l2 with
    ...
    | (x :: xs), (y :: ys) when x < y ->
```

The two cases you're missing are where the two heads are different i.e. `x < y` or `x > y`. If `x < y` then since the lists are sorted, there are one or more elements at the front of `l2` which can be ignored since they cannot exist in `l1` e.g. if

`x = 5` and `l2 = [1;2;4;5]` then `[1;2;4]` can be discarded to find the next match.

I suggest you write a utility function which discards elements on the front of a list which cannot be found e.g.

```
//removes items from the front of l which cannot occur in a sorted list with head e
let rec skipUntil e l = ...
```

Once you have removed those elements you can continue the search.

The case where `x > y` is handled symmetrically.